# Vba code in original file to track all copied files

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to insert a code so we can track all copied excel files in the future?

The reason why: we are creating a template excel file that people can copy and fill in. The problem is that they regularly have to fill in the same information so instead of starting from the template they copy the already filled in template. 
If we decide to change the template, we want to change all the files that were copied so there are no multiple versions going around.
All the files are stored on a server in subfolders so We can access them all. Titles of the file will vary based on the wishes from the customer.

Comment: Hi @Wesley, are you thinking of doing all those operations of tracking copied files from Excel VBA?

Comment: You could use one of the .BuiltinDocumentProperties For example ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Comments") = "Version1"

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this function, you can search the subfolder on "Version 1" afterwards I guess?

Answer (score 1):

After reading you, I see that:

### Summary:

1. You have one single Template that everybody copies
2. You store all the filled templates on one Server Subfolder
3. Title of the Files varies from Customer's needs

### Challenges:

1. For Performance shake, you might need of a program than Excel to manage those files
2. Otherwise, it is possible to use Excel VBA, but is somehow/enough complicated so you would need to have an advanced skills and enough time to write everything handling that Subfolders' file renaming if you wish to collect the data in one Single Excel.

### Suggested Solution:

1. I recommend you to have **A Locked Worksheet + Workbook Excel
   Template** so your customers won't be able to edit its structure and
   it will keep all of your templates to be the same.
2. You better have some kind of the **Standard in the nomenclature of your Excel Files** which will help you use that description later on for search/filter/sorting ...
3. You can have a **Reset Button** as well within the Template where your customers will click and will empty all the fields effortless.
4. In short, If you wish to track of files being copies, you would need more than Excel VBA for that as you need to play with **A windows service** for you to track them.

Hope this will give you some ideas. All the Best!

Comment: Thanks, it's not that we are afraid that they mess up our template because we have a backup template which they have no access to so we can always replace it if needed. It more because if we update the code in the template files or add another insert field we want to forse these changes also in the already copied excel files. The naming is indeed a good point, Everybody should start their file with a specific nomenclature

Comment: Do you still have some challenges to address please? I saw you've not voted and accepted my response yet [those are the signs of our accomplishment in this fully free assistance ;) ]

Comment: for one the other comment was exactly what I was looking for actually. If I use ```ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Comments") = "Version1" ``` it's very easy to track all the files that were copies and have this code. Looping through folder and subfolders is easy., even with VBA this is all possible.